# Alternatives to OpenBabel for converting *large* files?

Tags: software, software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, openbabel

I have been using `OpenBabel` as a handy-tool for converting small files without any issues.

Now, I am working with graphene-like systems with hundreds or even thousands of atoms, and the conversion of a 1360-line `XYZ` file to `MOL2` format is taking more than 48 hours! My notebook is running Ubuntu 22.04 (64-bit), with an Intel i7 12-core processor and 24GB RAM.

There seems to be a problem with trying to do this using `OpenBabel`, whether directly or via third-party programs that use it as a plugin (like MAESTRO, Avogadro, etc.).

**Is there any other tool for file conversion than does not use `OpenBabel` (or any library from it) that can be used for large files?**

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps you can show us the `XYZ` file that you're trying to convert to `MOL2` format, so that we can try to do some tests? SE posts [can have up to 30,000 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176445/391772) so 1360 lines might be okay. If it doesn't fit, perhaps you can put it in a folder called "9627" [here](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters).

Comment: My strong guess (knowing your research) is that you'r running into problems with guessing the bond orders on a nanotube or graphene flake, for example. Determining bond orders in a ~25k atom PDB file is easy .. figuring out the Kekule bond orders in fused ring systems is a hard problem.

Comment: Why do you need the file in mol2 format?

Comment: I am using DESMOND to run molecular dynamics and its input files are prepare using MAESTRO, that convert the files using OPENBABEL. MAESTRO is getting stuck reading large files in XYZ format but if the file is in MOL2, it read it without any problem. I thought that converting first, and load it after will solve my issue.

Comment: @NikeDattani, I didn't find the folder "9627".

Comment: Was the file too big to insert into a `code` block? SE posts can have up to 30,000 characters. As for the 9627 folder, you have full permissions on the Git repository to make folders, but if you need help I can make the folder (just tell me the name of the XYZ file that you're planning to upload there, so that I can create the folder, since we apparently can't make blank folders in Git, I'd need to make a dummy file with the same name as your XYZ file).

Comment: I'd like to propose an edit. The problem isn't in converting large files. Its with converting large graphene-like systems. I can convert 25k atom PDB files in seconds, but yes 1300 atoms of graphene can take a lot of time.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison you are absolute right, my system is formed by long carbon nanotubes with -OH and -COOH decorations. Following your suggestion, I will add this information to the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Large files aren't a problem *per se*. Open Babel easily handles 25k atom proteins. You're hitting slow conversion because you have files with many fused aromatic rings, e.g., graphene flakes, nanotubes, etc.

The problem you're describing is based on the need to perceive bond orders. (The `mol2` format requires bond orders and aromaticity to define types, etc.)

The current algorithm in Open Babel uses **backtracking** when finding the correct Kekulé assignment. This can require a *lot* of time on fused ring systems because there are a lot of potential paths to check.

It's possible to turn off bond order assignment when reading XYZ files, using the `-as` flag (i.e., read single bonds only)

`obabel file.xyz -O file.mol2 -as`

Here's benzene:

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
benzene example
 12 12 0 0 0
SMALL
GASTEIGER

@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C           0.0000    1.4027    0.0000 C.3     1  UNL1       -0.0309
      2 H           0.0000    2.4903    0.0000 H       1  UNL1        0.0309
      3 C          -1.2148    0.7014    0.0000 C.3     1  UNL1       -0.0309
      4 H          -2.1567    1.2451    0.0000 H       1  UNL1        0.0309
      5 C          -1.2148   -0.7014    0.0000 C.3     1  UNL1       -0.0309
      6 H          -2.1567   -1.2451    0.0000 H       1  UNL1        0.0309
      7 C           0.0000   -1.4027    0.0000 C.3     1  UNL1       -0.0309
      8 H           0.0000   -2.4903    0.0000 H       1  UNL1        0.0309
      9 C           1.2148   -0.7014    0.0000 C.3     1  UNL1       -0.0309
     10 H           2.1567   -1.2451    0.0000 H       1  UNL1        0.0309
     11 C           1.2148    0.7014    0.0000 C.3     1  UNL1       -0.0309
     12 H           2.1567    1.2451    0.0000 H       1  UNL1        0.0309
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1     1     2    1
     2     1     3    1
     3     1    11    1
     4     3     4    1
     5     3     5    1
     6     5     6    1
     7     5     7    1
     8     7     8    1
     9     7     9    1
    10     9    10    1
    11     9    11    1
    12    11    12    1
```

Now that seems useless, since all the carbon atoms are `C.3`  instead of `C.ar` .. but it's trivial using Python or another script to find-and-replace the atom typings.

The other thing is to fix the C-C bonds:

```
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1     1     2    1
     2     1     3   ar
     3     1    11   ar
     4     3     4    1
     5     3     5   ar
     6     5     6    1
     7     5     7   ar
     8     7     8    1
     9     7     9   ar
    10     9    10    1
    11     9    11   ar
    12    11    12    1
```

Besides Open Babel, it's possible to use RDKit with the [`xyz2mol` package](https://github.com/jensengroup/xyz2mol) and save to `SDF` format, converting the resulting `.mol` or `.sdf` file to `.mol2`.